# How to auto-click on button in the website that opened in new tab

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Need your help below, all codes below are from "example.com" assuming:

`<a href="http://www.example.org" target="vo1" onclick="gp(1)" rel="nofollow">Click Me</a>`

When I click on "Click Me", it will run the function "gp()" below

```
<script>
function gp(pul){
    var qal = "vo";
    var tul = document.querySelectorAll('[target="'+qal+pul+'"]');    

    [].slice.call(tul).forEach(
        function(link){
            setTimeout(function(){
                if(pul == 1){
                    window.open("http://www.example.com",qal+pul);

                }else
                if(pul == 2){
                    window.open("http://www.example.com",qal+pul);
                }
            },1000);
        }
    );
}

</script>
```

**What script should I add in the above script to auto-click on "testbutton" below when "example.com" is load on the new tab? I need the pop out message to be appeared in new tab.**

All codes below are for pop out message.

`<button style="display:none;" id="myBtn">testbutton</button>`

```
<div id="myModal" class="modal">

  <!-- Modal content -->
  <div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <span class="close">&times;</span>
      <h2>Modal Header</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <p>Some text in the Modal Body</p>
      <p>Some other text...</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <h3>Modal Footer</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

```
<script>
// Get the modal
var modal = document.getElementById("myModal");

// Get the button that opens the modal
var btn = document.getElementById("myBtn");

// Get the <span> element that closes the modal
var span = document.getElementsByClassName("close")[0];

// When the user clicks the button, open the modal 
btn.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "block";
}

// When the user clicks on <span> (x), close the modal
span.onclick = function() {
  modal.style.display = "none";
}

// When the user clicks anywhere outside of the modal, close it
window.onclick = function(event) {
  if (event.target == modal) {
    modal.style.display = "none";
  }
}
</script>
```

```
<style>
body {font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}

/* The Modal (background) */
.modal {
  display: none; /* Hidden by default */
  position: fixed; /* Stay in place */
  z-index: 1; /* Sit on top */
  padding-top: 100px; /* Location of the box */
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%; /* Full width */
  height: 100%; /* Full height */
  overflow: auto; /* Enable scroll if needed */
  background-color: rgb(0,0,0); /* Fallback color */
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.4); /* Black w/ opacity */
}

/* Modal Content */
.modal-content {
  position: relative;
  background-color: #fefefe;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid #888;
  width: 80%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2),0 6px 20px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.19);
  -webkit-animation-name: animatetop;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 0.4s;
  animation-name: animatetop;
  animation-duration: 0.4s
}

/* Add Animation */
@-webkit-keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0} 
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

@keyframes animatetop {
  from {top:-300px; opacity:0}
  to {top:0; opacity:1}
}

/* The Close Button */
.close {
  color: white;
  float: right;
  font-size: 28px;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.close:hover,
.close:focus {
  color: #000;
  text-decoration: none;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.modal-header {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}

.modal-body {padding: 2px 16px;}

.modal-footer {
  padding: 2px 16px;
  background-color: #5cb85c;
  color: white;
}
</style>
```

**The basic idea is, I am in the urlA, when I click on one link, it will load the same urlA in the new tab. In this new tab, when it load, I want it to auto-click on the button to trigger the pop out message.
Thanks in advance for your help.**

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean with auto click?

The new tab, does it open a site made by you?

---

You should use url params for that, I will make for you a very basic example, you have to improve this, if you want to have more functionality in it.

For html, you use:

```
<a target="_blank" href="http://example.com/index.html?clickButton=true">Link</a>
```

The parameter is added to the href link, clickbutton=true.

for the JS you simply write something like this:

```
function buttonClick() {
alert('pop up')
}

let url = window.location.href;
let params = url.split('?');
let myparam = params[1].split('=');
if (myparam[1] === 'true') buttonClick();
```

I just got the url string and used some split functions to get the result of the parameter.
There is for sure specific functions to do this in a better way, but I never used them, so I give you some basic JS code.

Comment: autoclick on the button to trigger the pop out message in the new tab.

Comment: Yap, when I click on the link, it will open the same url in the new tab, the website is example.com, same url where I click on the link

Comment: why dont you just add a parameter to the url, and once the new url is opened, your JS checks if the param exists, if so, it calls the function of the button.